# How to create a curved slider cell with box shadow and dynamic colour with CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a slider cell that has its content, but then has a curved bottom with a box shadow. The background colour of the bottom and of the slider cell will be dynamic. My issue is with positioning and using the right approach (pseudo vs SVG etc).

I need it to look like this:

[image: layout]

I have tried adding a new div within my slider cell, and then applying styling and/or a pseudo-element. The issue is that I break the layout of the page, and I can't get content within the cell aligned, I can't get the white background to the shape, and I can't get the content below positioned correctly.

```
  .image-slider__curve {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50% / 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    bottom: -90px;
    z-index: 1;

      &::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: -1;
      }
  }
```

My HTML is structured as follows:

```html
<div class="image-slider__cell">
    <div class="content">Heading</div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">...</div>
    <div class="image-slider__curve"></div>
</div>
```

Currently the positioning is breaking and the shape and alignments are off. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.image-slider__cell {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-slider__cell .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    max-width: 100px;
}

.image-slider__cell .image-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* the next tree lines are only used to center text */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.image-slider__curve {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 100% 100%;
    bottom: -90px;
    background-color: rgb(4, 153, 151);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -2px gray;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-slider__cell">
    <div class="content">Heading Heading Heading</div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">Image</div>
    <div class="image-slider__curve"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two pseudo elements, one for the colored part and the other for the shadow:

```css
.box {
  margin:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background:radial-gradient(80% 80% at top center, green 98.5%,transparent 100%);
}
.box:before {
  background:radial-gradient(80% 80% at top center, transparent 96%,#000 96% 99%,transparent 100%);
  filter:blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```